# Importing a class using decorator as a tag

Tags: python, python-import, python-decorators

I am trying to find the pattern (or a specific implementation example) of a dynamic class import using a decorator as a tag.

Use case is for a workflow application that has different modules, each a user-defined class, such as a PredictionModule, CrawlerModule, WriterModule, etc (these are, for example, the base classes of some modules). The Workflow manager is provided a file, e.g. `classes.py` that contains all user-defined classes.

Within the workflow manager, I want to dynamically import the necessary classes for the workflow modules from `classes.py`. Given that our workflow have specific modules, I was wondering if there was a way to do the following:

```
# classes.py

@prediction_module
class PredictionModule:
   stuff

@crawler_module
class CrawlerModuleWithCustomName:
   stuff

@potentially_decorated_or_not
class OtherIrrelevantClassUsedSomewhereElse
   stuff
```

Then, Workflow manager should import PredictionModule and CrawlerModuleWithCustomName because they have the required decorators `@prediction_module` and `@crawler_module`, so that we can instantiate the modules when the workflow is running (and ignore OtherIrrelevantClassUsedSomewhereElse; mainly, I would like to avoid doing `from classes.py import *` and then type checking each top level imported classes on whether they fit the required Base Classes).

My guess was that decorators might be used for this, because I have seen something that *might* be similar with flask decorators, but I wasn't sure if this was the correct direction to dig in, or whether I should be looking somewhere else.

Thanks!

Comment: "Within the workflow manager, I want to dynamically import the necessary classes for the workflow modules from classes.py" so, you don't *import classe*, you *import modules*. i.e. you will import `classes.py` and that will make all of the modules available, it isn't really clear what you are expecting

Comment: In any case, you should just `import classes`, and then your decorator can *register* your decorated class appropriately (by adding to some container, or some custom class) that your workflow knows about and uses

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's what I ended up doing, thank you. I created a package-specific globals that stored the imported classes, registered with the class's function and the file-name it was imported from. Works like a charm!